# Не могут создаться куки в PHP

Tags: php, cookie

Уже неделю мучаюсь с куки в PHP . Просто скажито что тут НЕ ТАК

```
 $test = setcookie("hey", "itst", time()+3600*24*30, '/');
 echo json_encode($test);
```

и всегда false (PHP 7.0.26)

Comment: куки передаются в хедерах. А значит, этот вызов должен быть до любого вывода тела ответа (тегов) пользователю. Иногда один залетный пробел в самом начале файла может приводить к подобных эффектам.

Comment: `setcookie` возвращает тип `boolean`, Вы пытаетесь значение типа `boolean` декодировать как json и поэтому `json_decode` возвращает `false`. Попробуйте просто `echo $test`, а в остальном зависит от контекста вызова, как уже подметил комментатор выше.

Comment: @RTK а я не могу вывести просто $test JS такое не выводит

Answer (score 1):

Из документации:

> Если перед вызовом функции клиенту уже передавался какой-либо вывод
>   (теги, пустые строки, пробелы, текст и т.п.), setcookie() потерпит
>   неудачу и вернет FALSE. Если setcookie() успешно отработает, то вернет
>   TRUE. Это, однако, не означает, что клиентское приложение (браузер)
>   правильно приняло и обработало cookie.

Источник: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Проверьте, где Вы вызываете функцию `setcookie()`, возможно вы это делаете после того, как сработал какой-то echo, print или тому подобное. Проверку следует произвести не только в файле, где выполняется `setcookie()`, но в файлах которые подключены с помощью `include`, `require` и т.п., а также в файлах которые подключат ваш файл.

Также, для дебага, можно поставить `exit();` прямо перед `setcookie()` и посмотреть что вернет браузер. Возможно, там затесался какой-то пробел.

Comment: конект к бд как то будет мешать ? Добавление в дб запросов , вытаскивание из него запросов и т д мешает ?

Comment: так же если setcookie("text", "12345", time() + 3600*24*30, '/'); сделаю в САМОМ начале файла то всё равно не сработает